# Bash converting double quotes to single quotes

Tags: bash

I'm having a problem with my bash script that is driving me up the wall. I've got a piece of code that's supposed to bring in some files:

```
if [[ $FILENODE == null ]]
then
    cp "/home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa*" "$JOBDIR"
    cp "$IN" "$JOBDIR"
else
    echo "Copying files from node$FILENODE"
    rcp "node$FILENODE-ib:$JOBDIR/hg18.fa*" "node$FILENODE-ib:$JOBDIR/$IN" "$JOBDIR"
fi
```

Usually we will be falling into the first part of the conditional, and so the cp command is supposed to expand the wildcard in the first argument. I understand I need to double quote my arguments to ensure they are expanded. However, when I execute this script with bash -x, this is what I see:

```
+ cp '/home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa*' /usr/tmp/707361.master.cl.osumc.edu
cp: cannot stat `/home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa*': No such file or directory
+ cp '*.sort.bam' /usr/tmp/707361.master.cl.osumc.edu
cp: cannot stat `*.sort.bam': No such file or directory
```

For some reason, bash seems to be not only ignoring my double quotes, but turning them into single quotes. The variables are getting expanded, but not the wildcards. If anyone can explain what is going on here, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: As suggested by some, I have tried both removing the double quotes, and moving the trailing double quote to exclude the wildcard. This does not change the output!

Comment: The output from `bash -x` always has single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not quote the file path if you want globbing:

```
cp /home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa* "$JOBDIR"
```

Comment: Thanks - but the globbing still does not work even without the quotes.

Comment: try `echo /home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa*`, perhaps you don't have any files matching this expansion

Comment: This is right - there was a mistake in the file path. Now that it's corrected, everything works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Double quotes permit parameter expansion, *but they still inhibit glob expansion*. Move the glob wildcards outside the quotes.

```
cp "/home/dash/reference/hg18_bowtie_build/hg18.fa"* "$JOBDIR"
```

As for the second, create an array.

```
files=(foo*)
cp "${files[@]}" "$bar"
```

Comment: Thank you! I see the mistake in the second part of the conditional. But moving the quotes does not change the output of bash -x.

Comment: If it doesn't match anything at that point then there isn't anything *to* match.

Comment: If I had the reputation, I'd mark you up! There was a mistake in the file path. Thanks!

Comment: So I do! Better late than never.